# Exploitability of scenario

Tags: authentication

We have an home grown application that you must log into to use (using ldap credentials).  Once logged in the credentials you entered are used to communicate with the API and database and retrieve work assigned to you.  However, when opening an assignment, this pulls a file off of a network share as the currently logged in user (to windows, not the application).  Now 99% of the time, this is going to be the same user, however that still seems wrong to me, but the developer states that this behavior is by design (since there are policies to lock / not share your computer), and I can't argue.

Can anyone thing of a way this could be exploited, or am I being overly cautious?

Comment: I don't understand where the application is running, whether it is a thick or thin application, whether the application is returning a file path to be resolved by the client or if the file access is tunnelled through the local/remote application.....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the setup correctly, on the one hand you authenticate to the application to retrieve some data from it and then, independently, a Windows share is accessed (probably triggered by the application).

In that case the user who is logged in can access the data without the application anyway. He may not know **where** to look for the data but if the rights are set up correctly on the share it is more a way to hide from him what he has access to than to prevent someone else to access it.

If the above assumptions are correct there are no obvious security issues with this dual access.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct.  I only came across it as I sign into my workstation with a standard account, but had to log into the application as an administrator, and was confused when I was getting access denied.